# How can I create Dropbox-like functionality with FreeNAS?

Tags: nas, dropbox, freenas

I have several FreeNAS boxes scattered around the world (several terabytes of storage on each NAS) and have been doing manual rsyncs to keep them in line with each other. I would -really- like some kind of Dropbox-like service running on each of them, so that updates on any given box propagate automatically, to all other boxes. Has anyone ever tried to build something like this? I don't need total filesystem synchronization, but I want something damn near it.

I also don't want to use some kind of third-party hosting (S3?) for this, it should really be peer-to-peer. Any advice?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/128590/alternative-to-dropbox-on-my-server

Answer (score 3):

A possibile solution is [unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/): it could be used to syncornize stuff in different directions.

It is able to detect conflict and will ask for manual fixes.

It works on ssh connection, so it is secure, and you can mix operating systems too (I used form linux, macosx and windows) and saved my days.

For more information [see also my small blog review](http://gioorgi.com/tag/unison/).